# Increase content summary length in MailChimp

Tags: rss, mailchimp

I am using merge tags to display RSS feed items in a MailChimp template. I use the following merge tag to display the content summary

```
*|FEEDITEM:CONTENT_TEXT|*
```

But it only shows about 8 to 10 words. I want to increase the length of summary to about 25 words. Is there anyway to define content summary length in MailChimp? Or will I have to modify my RSS feeds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I discovered later that this text is fetched from  or  tags of RSS/Atom. You need to edit the RSS/Atom to modify this.

Comment: How did you adjust the RSS/Atom?